# Computed property not updated with navigator.onLine, in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use Vue.js computed properties to watch the online status of my app.
Basically, I have the following Vue setup:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    computed: {
        onLine: function (){
            return navigator.onLine;
        }
    }
})
```

And the following markup:

```
<div id="app">
    <div>{{ onLine }}</div>
</div>
```

I expected that when I would connect/disconnect my computer from the network, the "onLine" property would change between true and false. However, this doesn't happen...

The only way I could have it change is that one:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        onLine: navigator.onLine // initial status
    }
})

window.addEventListener('online',  function(){
    app.onLine = true;
});

window.addEventListener('offline',  function(){
    app.onLine = false;
});
```

There must be something that I don't understand about Vue computed properties. Who could tell me why it didn't work the way I expected ?

Comment: I think your second approach would be the proper way to approach it. As far as I understand it, computed properties would react to the `data` changing, not just any thing you pass to it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess that the problem is that `navigator.online` is not a reactive property. Check the [Vue guide](http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html) and try something like `Vue.nextTick(callback)` or the getter-like behavior

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but I solved it by using methods to listen that brings Vue.js
http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      onLine: navigator.onLine // initial status
    }
  });

  function updateConnectionStatus() {
    app.$set('onLine', navigator.onLine); // this method
  }

  window.addEventListener('online', updateConnectionStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateConnectionStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

So if memory serves observed objects must be primitive or plain, "native" objects cannot be directly observed. And the library will ignore attempts to do so.

Comment: I think that was just a typo. He mentioned the bottom way works but not the top like he was hoping.

Comment: @shaun-hubbard: Sorry, "View" was just a typo. As for the part of my code that you copied into jsfiddle, I know that it works. My question was why the other thing that I tried didn't work.