# Get Local Storage Data when internet is online

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js, vuejs2

So I'm trying to get Local Storage data when the internet is online using Vuejs. My ToDo app stack in Vuejs/Laravel/MySQL. Basically, I'm storing data in localStorage when the internet is online. Also, I have added all the functionalities of the ToDo app with offline capabilities like adding, deleting and editing the todo item.
I'm unable to post the local storage data to MySQL Database.

```
updateAllTodos() {
  let data = { todos: this.todos };
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    axios.post(this.api + "/update_all", data).then((res) => {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.todos));
    });
  } else {
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.todos)));
  }
},
```

How can I post the localStorage data when the Internet is Online?

Comment: localstorage is an offline storage which is stored in the browser ... it can be access online and also online ... did I get it right that you want to keep checking the change in the offline->online status and when online, sync the items to the DB ? if that's the case - see this pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532195/computed-property-not-updated-with-navigator-online-in-vue-js

Comment: @Mr.P  That’s correct. So i want that, if the internet connection goes offline, I want the ToDo data to be saved in Local Storage (which my app is already doing).  Next,  the new ToDo item which i saved in offline mode in local storage. I want that local storage data to be synced with DB when internet is Online. Thanks

Comment: so you have to create this "watched" property that will be checking online/offline status (pls see the link I posted) ... 

And based on that property, you decide where to store :) if "offline" you use localStorage as your "database" ... and whenever the connection becomes online, you check you localstorage (if there is something stored, save it in the database) and switcht to storage to your database... does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this (update onLine status) by using event listener and set the variable true/false.
Later you can watch to the data property and do something accordingly.

```
  data() {
    return {
      isOnLine:navigator.onLine
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     window.addEventListener('online', () => {this.isOnLine = true});
     window.addEventListener('offline', () => {this.isOnLine = false});
  },
  watch: {
   onLine: function (val) {
      if(this.isOnLine){
        // make axios call here
      }
    },
  }
```